# How to untrack all deleted files in Git

Tags: git, version-control

What's the command to untrack all deleted files in Git?

I know there's a command to untrack a file by name (`git rm myfile`)

But I'd like to untrack all the deleted files, without caring about how they're named.

Comment: "untrack" as in remove them from history?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In the newer versions of git, those files are automatically untracked with `git add --update`.

Comment: But if I run `git add -all`, won't files that aren't tracked be added to the repository? I don't want that to happen.

Comment: Yes, it's extremely unintuitive but it seems that `git add -u` is working, that is, you must use `git add -u` to untrack deleted files. Thanks a lot!

Comment: YES! how is this question not more popular? Thank you so much.

Comment: I think you're better off deleting hte old comment. Some people might read it and just type it in, before reading the edit.

Comment: @125_m_125 I did git add --update and it looks like the deleted files have been added to the staging area. I tried to commit thinking that would solve the problem, but now the files just stay in the staging area. If I git reset HEAD file it just takes them out of the staging area to where they were before.

Comment: But `git add --update` also adds modified files. Not only deleted ones.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the [`git clean`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-clean.html) command?

Comment: If I understand the description ("Cleans the working tree by recursively removing files that are not under version control, starting from the current directory."), this is the opposite of what I would like to do. What I would like to do is having the files no tracked anymore by git. The files are already deleted.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ git diff-files --diff-filter=D --name-only -z | xargs -0 git rm
```